# Does an exception in one statement in a try block cause control flow to bypass any remaining statements in the try block?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I have some C++ code that looks like this:

```
void Student::addCourse(Course cVal, string gr) throw(...) {
    try {
        GradedCourse c(cVal, gr);  // If an exception is thrown here...
        coursesTaken.insert(c);    // will this statement be executed?
    } catch(...) {
        throw;
    }
}
```

The `GradedCourse` constructor may throw an exception if `gr`, which contains a grade for a course, is found to be invalid by the constructor.  If such an exception occurs, will any further statements inside the `try` block be executed?  Can I be sure that such an exception will result in no attempt to insert the `GradedCourse` into `coursesTaken` (which is an STL set)?  I've searched both Stack Overflow and Google without much success.

Comment: yes, your second statement will never be executed if the first statement throws an exception.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen If you want to answer a question, why not post an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: Note (because I see too much of this): the try/catch/rethrow is unnecessary, as is the `throw(...)` specification...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If `GradedCourse c(cVal, gr);` throws an exception, nothing else inside the `try` block will be executed.

Comment: Wow, I never expected Stack Overflow to be this fast in answering questions like this...

Comment: Glad you were positively surprised ;)

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand what you are trying to ask, but your title and question itself are both asking conflicting things. :)

If an exception is thrown inside of a try block, execution immediately jumps to the catch block that handles that exception, bypassing all other statements.

[Here is the documentation on exceptions.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/) It does not directly address your issue, but it does cover other important things such as exception nesting, or chaining exception handlers.

Comment: I've already looked at the linked article.  I wouldn't have asked this question if the information I needed was there.